# query retuerning Resource id #10

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the number of the rows with a specific column name . When i am executing the query, no error is showing but the output given is just Resource id #10. I am a beginner in php and mysql field . Can anyone help me out ?
I tried the given below code

```
    $sql ="SELECT column1,column2 FROM table1 WHERE user_id='name' GROUP BY time_stamp";    
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $count=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<form action=table2.php method=GET>";
        echo"<tr>";
        $row_no="SELECT COUNT(time_stamp) FROM table1";
        $row_num = mysql_query($row_no);



        echo "<td>" .$count. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row["column1"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row["column2"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row_num. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."<input class=btn type=submit value=Delete". "></td>";

        echo"</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
        $count=$count+1;
    }
```

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_row()` after `mysql_query($row_no)` in `while` loop

Comment: also query should be `SELECT COUNT(time_stamp) as count FROM table1`

Comment: Do **not** use `mysql_`nothing to do nothing, it's *deprecated* function. You need to change it to `mysqli_` functions or, even better, `PDO` objects;

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the array for the second query you execute and then use it's column for echo

```
$sql ="SELECT column1,column2 FROM table1 WHERE user_id='name' GROUP BY time_stamp";    
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<form action=table2.php method=GET>";
    echo"<tr>";
    $row_no="SELECT COUNT(time_stamp) AS cnt FROM table1";
    $row_num = mysql_query($row_no);
    $row_num_res = mysql_fetch_array($row_num);

    echo "<td>" .$count. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row["column1"]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row["column2"]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row_num_res["cnt"]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."<input class=btn type=submit value=Delete". "></td>";

    echo"</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    $count=$count+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the count in the second query. You can do it using `mysql_fetch_row`

```
$sql ="SELECT column1,column2 FROM table1 WHERE user_id='name' GROUP BY time_stamp";    
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $count=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<form action=table2.php method=GET>";
        echo"<tr>";
        $row_no= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(time_stamp) as count FROM table1");
        $row_num = mysql_fetch_row($row_no);
        echo "<td>" .$row_num[0]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row["column1"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row["column2"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row_num. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."<input class=btn type=submit value=Delete". "></td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
        $count=$count+1; 
    }
```

Note: Do not use `mysql_*` These functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.